# R - unexpected result using foverlaps with dates

Tags: r, date, data.table, overlap

I have two data tables with millions of rows where there are pairs of `IDs` with partial date overlapping. Please see a very short example below:

```
library(data.table)
dt1 <- data.table(ID=720,
                  startdate=as.IDate("2000-01-01"),
                  enddate=as.IDate("2017-10-09"))
dt2 <- data.table(ID=720,
                  startdate=as.IDate("2000-06-08"),
                  enddate=as.IDate("2020-04-12"))
```

I would like to find the **overlapping** period of time between the two datasets. I am attempting to do so using `foverlaps`:

```
setkey(dt1, ID, startdate, enddate)
setkey(dt2, ID, startdate, enddate)

foverlaps(dt1, dt2, by.x=c("ID", "startdate", "enddate"),
          by.y=c("ID", "startdate", "enddate"), type='within', nomatch = 0L)

Empty data.table (0 rows and 5 cols): ID,startdate,enddate,i.startdate,i.enddate
```

The code above returns an empty data table, because the date range in `dt1` is not **completely** within the date range in `dt2`.

However, I was expecting a data table with whatever date range is common for the two datasets, which would be:

```
       ID  startdate    enddate
  1: 720  2000-06-08 2017-10-09
```

Is there anyway to achieve that using `foverlaps`? If not, is there any alternative that would work just as fast for million of rows?

Answer (score 3):

I think you firstly need to change `type='within'` to `type = 'any'`

As `within` means date range in `dt1` sits within `dt2`

After that, you may need to find the overlapping date range by yourself (which is pretty strightforward). As `foverlaps`  just does the `join`.

```r
library(data.table)
dt1 <- data.table(ID=720,
                  startdate=as.IDate("2000-01-01"),
                  enddate=as.IDate("2017-10-09"))
dt2 <- data.table(ID=720,
                  startdate=as.IDate("2000-06-08"),
                  enddate=as.IDate("2020-04-12"))


setkey(dt1, ID, startdate, enddate)
setkey(dt2, ID, startdate, enddate)

result <- foverlaps(dt1, dt2, by.x=c("ID", "startdate", "enddate"),
          by.y=c("ID", "startdate", "enddate"), type='any', nomatch = 0L)
result
#>     ID  startdate    enddate i.startdate  i.enddate
#> 1: 720 2000-06-08 2020-04-12  2000-01-01 2017-10-09

result[,`:=`(overlapping_start=fifelse(i.startdate>=startdate,i.startdate,startdate),
            overlapping_end = fifelse(i.enddate<=enddate,i.enddate,enddate))]

result[,.(ID,overlapping_start,overlapping_end)]
#>     ID overlapping_start overlapping_end
#> 1: 720        2000-06-08      2017-10-09
```

<sup>Created on 2020-04-19 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Or omit the `type` argument as "any" is the default.